# Which Method is used to Update Rest Api Data on click Tableview Cell

Tags: ios, swift3, tableview

I Have Rest Api Data Display in Tableview , I want different data in same ViewController and reload data on Tableview using Rest api , I want to know how to update my data on same page After click on different categories and Subcategory .

[this image for menu of category and sub category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgCZP.png)

[This is my viewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbIM3.png)

Comment: it is expandable UITableView

Comment: Try to reload the table

Comment: or you can - (void)reloadSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation

Comment: Yes This is expandable Tableview .

Comment: and i want to change my data from rest api

Comment: @sapna which data?
Table's data or ViewController data?

Comment: Rest Api data @KetanOdedra

Comment: Then simply call your api on click of tableview  didSelectRowAt method
    `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
        {
            Apicall()
        }`

Comment: rest api data successfully called but i want to update my data when data is reloaded

Comment: @sapna u mean you want to use pagination?

Comment: yes @KetanOdedra

Answer (score 0):

You Can Do This

```
var page:Int = 0
var isPageRefreshing:Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
     YourApi(page1: 0)
     }

   func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if(self.mytableview.contentOffset.y >= 
        (self.mytableview.contentSize.height - 
        self.mytableview.bounds.size.height)) {
            if(isPageRefreshing==false) {
                 isPageRefreshing=true
                 print(page)
                 page = page + 1
                 YourApi(page1: page)
        }
    }
}
```

In your api code

```
func YourApi(page1 :Int) {
    let mypage = String(page1)
    let Request: String = String.init(format:"apiName/%@",mypage)
    print(Request)
 }
```

Comment: Can i Use Pagination in UIPageViewController for swipe Up and Down Pages,when my pages swipe up and down my data is loaded according to that

Comment: Yes, You can but i suggest you to use TableView..mostly UIPageViewController used for sliding Left or Right.

Comment: Recently i work on uipageviewcontroller and every page i have tableview , so every page i need to call rest api data for different data view .. i want to declare once rest api data and use many other pages of uipageviewcontroller , is this possible using pagination ..  ..

Comment: sure@Ketan Odedra